# BootstrapVue b-form-group label binding, label not showing

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

New to Vue.js, cannot get form group label to show in component. Am trying to create a component to save myself some time as will need to use this a lot of times.

Thanks

```
 <ZComplianceField :mylabel="foo" :property="user.applicationForm.rating" :isEditing="isEditing"></ZComplianceField>

<template>
  <b-form-group
    label-cols="4"
    label-cols-lg="2"
    label-size="sm"   

  >  
  <template slot="label">{{ mylabel }}</template>
    <b-form-input     
      size="sm"
      type="text"
      v-model="property"
      :disabled="!isEditing"
      :class="{view: !isEditing}"
    ></b-form-input>
  </b-form-group>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ZComplianceField",

  props: {
    mylabel: {
      required: true
    },
    property: {
      required: true
    },
    isEditing: {
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

'''

[image: label not showing up]

Comment: You're currently binding your `mylabel` prop to the data property `foo`. Do you have a data property named foo that's set to a string?

Comment: Additionally, if you don't have a data property called `foo` and is simply trying to set the label to the string `foo`, try rewriting it from `:mylabel="foo"` to `mylabel="foo"`. (notice the `:` is removed)

Comment: A little sidenote. If you aren't planning to do anything other than printing your label. Using the slot might be a bit overkill. You could instead add `:label="mylabel"` to your `b-form-group`, which would give the same result.

Comment: Thanks Hiws. I'll try this out later. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you´re binding your value `<ZComplianceField :mylabel="foo"></ZComplianceField>`.

Notice that you have a `:` in-front of `mylabel`. The `:` is shorthand for `v-bind`, which binds a data property.

What you want is to remove the `:`, so that your `foo` is treated a string.

Your other option is to define `foo` in your data and set it to a string.

```js
{
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      foo: "Some Label"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```